# Anchor link PDF work around

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, anchor

In IE currently anchor linking to a section on a PDF only works if the PDF in question is cached or has been downloaded recently on the user's computer.

Example

```
User clicks anchor link to pdf first time 
    PDF loads at the beginning of document
User goes back to website and clicks link again
    PDF loads at anchor linked position
```

Does anyone know of a work around in which the PDF will load at the desired position upon first clicking the link?

Note that the anchor links are of the type `#page=200` and fit these guidelines http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try and prefetch the PDF? Not sure how to do that though... Maybe in an Ajax call

Comment: There's a few of them and they are quite large, don't think this is a good idea. There's about 5 and they total like 2300 pages together.

Comment: That sounds kinda buggish.  Have you tried this in different versions of Reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution, while not perfect it works.

```
<div class="hidden" id="iframes"></div> //-- hidden div at bottom of page 

$(function() {
    var urls = ["url one", "url two", "etc..."];
    $(urls).each(function(index, url) {
        var iframe = $("<iframe />").attr({ src: url });
        $("#iframes").append(iframe);
    });
});
```